# How to set up expectations on the returned value of a mocked call with jmock?

Tags: java, jdbc, mocking, jmock

I'm using jmock to run some tests. I'd like to ensure that a third-party library will correctly call the following sequence on the JDBC API:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(connection).prepareStatement("test");
    oneOf(statement).setFetchSize(10);
    oneOf(statement).executeQuery();
}});
```

The `connection` object is created as such:

```
Mockery context = new Mockery();
connection = context.mock(Connection.class);
```

How do I create the `statement` object? I've tried these, neither worked:

```
// This creates an independent PreparedStatement mock, not the one that will be returned
// by the Connection.prepareStatement call
PreparedStatement statement = context.mock(PreparedStatement.class);

// This doesn't return a mock object, which I can pass to the oneOf() method.
PreparedStatement statement = oneOf(connection).prepareStatement("test");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `will(returnValue(...))` in your expectations to specify the result, like this:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(connection).prepareStatement("test"); will(returnValue(statement));
    // ...
}}
```

See also the [JMock cheat sheet](http://www.jmock.org/cheat-sheet.html).

Example that [I use in tests of Jaybird](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/blob/master/src/test/org/firebirdsql/ds/TestStatementHandlerMock.java#L148):

```
final PooledConnectionHandler conHandler = context.mock(PooledConnectionHandler.class);
final Statement statement = context.mock(Statement.class);
final Connection connectionProxy = context.mock(Connection.class);
final StatementHandler handler = new StatementHandler(conHandler, statement);

context.checking(new Expectations() {
    {
        oneOf(conHandler).getProxy(); will(returnValue(connectionProxy));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hah, I didn't get that at first, this disconnected `will(...)` DSL element that does some magic... Thanks!

Comment: @lukaseder Yes, in that regard, mockito feels a bit more natural. Although in my experience, each mock framework has their own positives and negatives. Essentially each method call in an expectation pushes additional state in.